# S3 bucket does not append new data objects

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-iot

I'm trying to send all my AWS IoT incoming sensor value messages to the same s3 bucket, but despite turning on versioning in my bucket, the file keeps getting overwritten and showing only the last input sensor value rather then all of them. I'm using "Store messages in an Amazon S3 bucket" direct from the AWS IoT console.  Any easy way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

So after further research and speaking with Amazon Dev support you actually cant append records tot he same file in S3 from the IoT console directly.  I mentioned this was a feature most IoT developers would want as a default, and he said it would likely be possible soon but not way to do it now.  Anyway the simplest workaound I tested is to set up a Kinesis stream with a firehose to a S3 bucket.  This will be constrained by an adjustable data size and stream duration but it works well otherwise.  It also allows you to insert a Lambda functino for data transform if needed.